# WooCommerce product attributes gone

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been working on my WordPress/WooCommerce site all morning.  An now, all of a sudden, my Product Attributes have no values.

If I add a new product attribute value (via the product attribute page), the new value also does not show.

If I look in the database, all the values are there and the data looks perfectly fine, references and all.

I've done nothing to the taxonomy terms (except read them in a little theme code I'm writing).

I've even looked at my GIT and nothing has changed that has any impact on product attributes.

I am completely stumped as nothing is making sense.  I'm starting to wonder if it's bad mojo, as another site of mine has also decided to magically stop working without reason.

Any ideas anyone?  I'm a tick away from going nutts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems to have been a full HDD on the VM machine the wordpress was running on. Once I freed up some space it all started working.